# Docker image producing different results with Python script between different host OS

Tags: python, docker, operating-system

I have been having trouble executing my python script in a remote server. However, when I build the docker image in my local machine (macOS Mojave), the docker image executes my script fine. The same docker image built in the remote server has issues with running the python script in the docker image. I was under the impression that the docker image would produce the same results regardless of its host OS. Correct if I'm wrong and what I can do to produce the same results in the remote server VM. What exactly is the underlying problem causing this issue? Should I request a new remote VM with certain specifications?

Comment: Can you show the script? What exactly is changing?

Comment: So the host OS running remotely is a centOS 7 version that is from 2014. Not sure if that makes a difference. The docket image builds the same version of Ubuntu and python compiler on top of that Ubuntu

Comment: Like you mentioned, changing host should not change the docker image. Only thing I can think of is maybe the way docker is being used, or maybe the script is doing something funky, or maybe different images are being downloaded.

Comment: Not sure if the host VM’s kernel matters but here is the info for that: `Kernel: Linux 3.10.0-957.1.3.el7.x86_64`. I’m trying to run using Python 3.6. The docker image appears to use the same python version and gcc across different host OS’s.

Comment: Without your `Dockerfile` and Python script, its hard to tell what might be the issue.

Comment: Ok so it turns out that the error message in my console was a bit misleading. I used FileZilla to transfer my python project and it didn’t transfer my project directory to its entirety. After using terminal-based scp command, the remote server environment didn’t have issues